# Reformatting & Concatenating Excel Spreadsheet Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data that's formatted like so:

```
-----   -----         -----                    -----        -----         -----  -----                            -----   -----
| A |   | B |         | C |                    | D |        | E |         | F |  | G |                            | H |   | I |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| SPC   | Department  | Sub Department         | Brand      | Colour Name | Size | Description                    | Price | Carton Size |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | White       | S    | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | White       | M    | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | White       | L    | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | White       | XL   | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | White       | 2XL  | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.75  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | Red         | S    | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | Red         | M    | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | Red         | L    | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | Red         | XL   | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | Red         | 2XL  | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.75  | 40          |
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | Red         | 3XL  | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.75  | 40          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 30"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 32"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 34"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 36"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 38"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 40"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue   | 42"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 30"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 32"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 34"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 36"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 38"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 40"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Lichen      | 42"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want it to be formatted like this:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| SPC   | Department  | Sub Department         | Brand      | Colour Names        | Sizes                              | Description                    | Price | Carton Size |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| KK400 | Polo Shirts | Mens Short Sleeve Polo | Kustom Kit | White, Red          | S, M, L, XL, 2XL, 3XL              | Kustom Kit Workwear Pique Polo | 4.25  | 40          |
| J172S | Workwear    | Mens Workwear          | Regatta    | Navy Blue, Lichen   | 30", 32", 34", 36", 38", 40", 42"  | Regatta Action Shorts          | 9.5   | 24          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

As you can see, I need the colours and sizes concatenating. Even though the polo above isn't available in 3XL in white, I still need the 3XL to be included in the final table. I also want the lower of the two prices.

There could be only one product per SPC or hundreds. Each needs to have its own line with all available options.

I'm pretty sure that this can be done using VBA, which I learnt some of very briefly in 1996-98 and forgot in 1999. I hope someone can help!

Comment: You managed to remember VBA for a whole year? Bravo.

Comment: @Polynomial All I remember now is `dim`. I don't know what it does.

Comment: `Dim` stands for "dimension" - it declares a variable. I only remember that because I used to code BASIC in the early 90s.

Comment: @Polynomial Ah, ok, thanks. I think I prefer `$` or, at a stretch, `var`.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the workbook? I can't tell exactly what you need combined, or on what reference you'd like to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do it.

Copy the below code into a new module in the workbook that has the data and run `createSummary`.

The code assumes your data is on the first worksheet and the SPC column is column A. I've also created the variables as public so I don't have to pass them to `copyToSummary`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ColumnOffsets
   Dept = 1
   SubDept = 2
   Brand = 3
   ColourName = 4
   Size = 5
   Desc = 6
   Price = 7
   CartonSz = 8
End Enum

Public rDetail As Range, rSum As Range
Public sColourNames As String, sSizes As String, dLowPrice As Double

Public Sub createSummary()
' Creates a summary worksheet in this workbook.
   Dim sht As Worksheet

   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' uncomment to make the macro run faster

   ' assumes the detail data is on the first worksheet with the header starting at A1
   Set rDetail = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
   Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=rDetail.Parent)
   sht.Name = "Summary"
   Set rSum = sht.Range("A1")

   ' sort detail to make sure all rows with the same SPC are next to each other
   Range(rDetail, rDetail.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Sort rDetail, Header:=xlYes

   ' copy header
   Range(rDetail, rDetail.End(xlToRight)).Copy
   rSum.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   ' move down to first data row
   Set rSum = rSum.Offset(1)
   Set rDetail = rDetail.Offset(1)

   ' loop thru data
   Do While rDetail <> ""

      ' summarise detail
      sColourNames = Append(rDetail.Offset(0, ColourName), sColourNames)
      sSizes = Append(rDetail.Offset(0, Size), sSizes)
      If dLowPrice = 0 Or rDetail.Offset(0, Price) < dLowPrice Then
         dLowPrice = rDetail.Offset(0, Price)
      End If

      ' add to sumary worksheet
      If rDetail <> rDetail.Offset(1) Then
         copyToSummary

         ' if screen updating is turned off, refersh the screen occasionally so Excel doesn' look like it is locked up.
         ' uncomment the below code to refresh the screen every 5 rows on the summary worksheet.
'         If rSum.Row Mod 5 = 0 Then
'            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            DoEvents
'            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'         End If

         ' reset summary variables
         sColourNames = ""
         sSizes = ""
         dLowPrice = 0
      End If

      Set rDetail = rDetail.Offset(1)

   Loop

   ' auto-fit summary page columns
   Range(rSum, rSum.End(xlToRight).End(xlUp)).Columns.AutoFit

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   MsgBox "Done."

End Sub

Private Function Append(ByVal sAppendThis As String, ByVal sToSummary As String) As String
' appends given value if it isn't already in summary.
' Note: The '|' are added to prevent "Blue" from matching to "Navy Blue". They are removed in copyToSummary.
   sAppendThis = "|" & Trim(sAppendThis) & "|"
   If Len(sToSummary) = 0 Then
      sToSummary = sAppendThis
   Else
      If InStr(LCase(sToSummary), LCase(sAppendThis)) = 0 Then
         sToSummary = sToSummary & ", " & sAppendThis
      End If
   End If
   Append = sToSummary
End Function

Private Sub copyToSummary()
' copies summed detail of current spc to summary sheet
   rSum.Activate
   rSum = rDetail
   rSum.Offset(0, Dept) = rDetail.Offset(0, Dept)
   rSum.Offset(0, SubDept) = rDetail.Offset(0, SubDept)
   rSum.Offset(0, Brand) = rDetail.Offset(0, Brand)
   rSum.Offset(0, ColourName) = Replace(sColourNames, "|", "")
   rSum.Offset(0, Size) = Replace(sSizes, "|", "")
   rSum.Offset(0, Desc) = rDetail.Offset(0, Desc)
   rSum.Offset(0, Price) = dLowPrice
   rSum.Offset(0, CartonSz) = rDetail.Offset(0, CartonSz)
   Set rSum = rSum.Offset(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It works though gives an error - 'run time 91'. Now let's read it and see if it refreshes my memory in any way!

Comment: Hm. I assume you are getting an error because your data isn't exactly how I recreated it. What line are you getting the error on?